# MySQL PHP data result as a href link

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table as a HTML page that goes and retrieves data from the MySQL database and then shows it in a table format.

How can I make one field of the data returned from the database a clickable `a href` link which would then load a new page giving detailed information on that entry?

i.e. table will shows results like

- firstname
- lastname
- email

How can I then make firstname a `a href` link that when clicked will load a separate page giving the rest of the information for the entry on its own page?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your HTML table to include an `<a>` tag to store the link. Add another column in your SQL table to store the link to extra information. Now use that column to populate the `href="*url you got from MySQL*"` inside your `<a>` tag in your HTML table. Like this, you can link every first name to whatever website you want to link to.

Answer (score 0):

Your database table should have some field(s) to identify each of its rows. It's called the **primary key** and it will be named something like id, userid, or similar.

With that in mind, I would:

- Recover the primary key from the database in the query.
- Echo this primary key field combined with the url of the detail page (say it is detail.php) and pass the primary key as a parameter (via get, that would be something like 'detail.php?id=*your_db_row_id*') inside the href of an *<a>* tag, like this:

  ```
  <a href="detail.php?id=your_db_row_id">firstname</a>
  ```

Echo this string instead of the firstname field, and you will get the link.

Comment: Thanks for the replies I have now managed to get it working partly thanks to the advice given here